# Trouble getting response from MySql db on Server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm working on an app that writes to a database and I just want some clarification on why something happens.  I have a AsyncTask class that I'm using to post and pull info.  It works fine.  But in my onPostExecute() I get a null pointer exception if my php script echoes.  If I comment out the echo, it all works fine.  Can someone clarify why this happens, and maybe correct something I'm doing wrong?  The code I've provided is what causes the error.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    switch (result){
        case "Registration Success...":
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case "One row inserted":
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

php

```
<?php

require "init.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];

$sql = "insert into product_info values('$name', '$email', '$mobile');";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
      echo "<br><h3>One Row inserted</h3> // if I leave this like this it causes the error. 
} else {
      //echo "Error in insertion". mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't have a closing quote on the echo string.  echo "<br><h3>One Row inserted</h3>" will fix it, I think

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)